# Why Does This Query Return Items from 2013?

Tags: php, mysql

This query:

```
SELECT 
        mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id,
        mantis_category_table.name, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y"),
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified, "%m-%d-%Y"),
        ROUND((mantis_bug_history_table.date_modified- mantis_bug_table.date_submitted)/ 86400, 1) as day_difference
    FROM 
        (mantis_bug_table INNER JOIN mantis_bug_history_table ON mantis_bug_table.id = mantis_bug_history_table.bug_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        mantis_category_table ON mantis_bug_table.category_id = mantis_category_table.id 
    WHERE
        FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y")
    BETWEEN '10/01/2014' AND '12/31/2014' 
    AND
        (((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="status") 
    AND 
        ((mantis_bug_history_table.new_value)="100")) 
    OR 
        (((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="new task")) 
    ORDER BY 
        mantis_bug_table.category_id, mantis_bug_table.date_submitted
```

Returns mostly valid data but also a couple of rows with these dates:

```
'39', 'Contracting', '12-12-2013', '01-14-2014', '32.7'
'40', 'Contracting', '12-12-2013', '01-14-2014', '32.7'
'41', 'Contracting', '12-19-2013', '03-12-2014', '82.9'
'42', 'Contracting', '12-31-2013', '01-14-2014', '13.9'
```

Can anyone explain why the between statement is not working 100%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y")
      BETWEEN '10/01/2014' AND '12/31/2014'
```

Look like rather different date formats to me.... one with `-` separator, the other with a `/` separator

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know that made a difference. However, the items from 2013 are still coming back even after the change. Can you spot anything else?

Comment: Because the date is being interpreted as a string? Try between date () and date ().

Comment: @Mike - Thanks Mike. I tried this: `BETWEEN DATE('10-01-2014') AND DATE('12-31-2014')`, but it didn't work at all. Now it returns nothing.

Comment: What happens if you don't convert? Use the SQL formats: WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted) BETWEEN DATE ('2014-10-01') AND DATE ('2014-12-31')

Comment: @Mike - It was actually the above date format also needed to be changed when using date(), like this: `FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%Y-%d-%m")
 BETWEEN DATE('2014-10-01') AND DATE('2014-12-31')`

Comment: Note no format string in FROM_UNIXTIME in my example. Make sure it stays in date format and not converted (even internally) to a string.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the OR part of your WHERE clause is going to bring in data you don't want. Let's reformat it.

```
WHERE 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(mantis_bug_table.date_submitted, "%m-%d-%Y") 
        BETWEEN '10/01/2014' AND '12/31/2014'
    AND (((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="status")
         AND ((mantis_bug_history_table.new_value)="100"))
    OR (((mantis_bug_history_table.field_name)="new task"))
```

It boils down to

```
WHERE 
    FROM_UNIXTIME ...
    AND ( ... AND ...)
    OR  ( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is too many transformations.

Try simple one:

```
WHERE
        mantis_bug_table.date_submitted
    BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```